# Escaping in double quotes in bash scripts

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, quoting

I am confused on this topic when reading the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide. According to the book,

> Bash script, when we quote a string, we set it apart and protect its literal meaning.

And

> Escaping is a method of quoting single characters. The escape (\) preceding a character tells the shell to interpret that character literally.

Seems that `\` is a "functional" character, but what if it's also put in a double quote? Will `\` be taken only as a literal or it still does escaping? For example,

```
echo \z  # z
echo "\z"  # \z  seems that the backslash is taken literally
echo \\  # \
echo "\\"  # \  so why this result is not \\ ?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`man bash`:

> Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $,  `,  \, [...]  The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the  following characters:  $,  `,  ", \, or newline.